# Show that for all $a,b,c>0$, $\frac 1 {\sqrt[3]{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}\geq\frac 3 {2(a+b+c)}$.

Tags: inequality

> Show that for all $a,b,c>0$, $\displaystyle\frac 1 {\sqrt[3]{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}\geq\frac 3 {2(a+b+c)}$.

I tried to cube the both sides, and expand it, but that'll be too troublesome, is there simpler ways? Thasnk you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

Using [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_of_the_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality),

$$\frac{a+b+b+c+c+a}3\ge \sqrt[3]{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}$$

Comment: Get it, Thanks~

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ, my pleasure